# Trapezoidal numerical integration in Modelica

Tags: modelica

I have two arrays "x" and "fy". I have to do the trapezoidal integration of array "fy" w.r.t array "x". I could not find a function in Modelica library. I have found a function in Buildings library but it does not help me exactly. Could you please suggest, if there is other function for this type of integration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought it was worth posting an alternative way to get the integral of an input relying on what Modelica does well. I found this nice example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16457839/5639728) that uses time and `der()`.

I'm not sure if the trapezoidal rule integration is done in the MSL but below is a simple function that implements the trapezoidal rule. [Here](http://pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/187/trapezoidal_rule.pdf) is a pdf with a nice summary and example.

In the future, you will likely have to write many of your own functions/models. There is still a lot of functionality Modelica needs such as a more complete verified and validated set of math functions like SciPy or GNU Standard Library which would have all sorts of integral, interpolation, etc. things that may be useful.

```
function integral_TrapezoidalRule "Integral of array y(x) using the trapezoidal rule"

  extends Modelica.Icons.Function;

  input Integer n(min=2) "length of array";
  input Real[n] x "dependent array";
  input Real[n] y "independent array";

  output Real integral "Resulting integral";

protected 
  Real[n-1] dx;

algorithm 
  integral := 0;

  for i in 1:n-1 loop
    dx[i] := x[i+1] - x[i];
    integral := integral + 0.5*dx[i]*(y[i+1]+y[i]);
  end for;

end integral_TrapezoidalRule;
```

Using the example from the pdf, calling the function with:

```
n = 6;
x = {2.1,2.4,2.7,3.0,3.3,3.6};
y = {3.2,2.7,2.9,3.5,4.1,5.2};
```

Yields:

```
integral = 5.22;
```