# Integration in OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have been trying to make an integral in open modelica. The integral that I would like to solve is the following:

```
W_fluido=Q/3600*∫〖Cp_fluido*dT, [Ti-Tf]
Where Cp_fluido= =(A+B*((C/T)/sinh⁡(C/T) )^2+D*((E/T)/cosh⁡(E/T) )^2))
```

I hope someone can help me

Comment: I think you can find this equation integrated in this great publication: https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?doi=10.1016/0378-3812%2881%2985002-9

Comment: For numeric integration, read this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457839/integration-of-function-in-modelica